# android coordinatorlayout with a linearlayout in parallax header?

Tags: android, header, parallax, android-coordinatorlayout

I've been looking everywhere for this w/ no luck.  The Android Support Design library seems to be designed for doing parallax only on an image, but I want a header that's more like a framelayout or linearlayout with a bunch of elements including an image w/ overlaid text and gradients on top of it.  I.e., a more complicated header that shrinks w/ text that parallaxes into the status bar title w/ a different font size.

Does anyone know how to do this?  I tried nesting a NestedScrollLayout but that's not what I want to do either :-(

Comment: Can you give an example of this effect in another app? I don't really understand what you're asking ...

Comment: I wish I had an example...our ux designer decided to make it challenging :-(
Imagine a Google Play store app listing with the image up top.  On top of the image, add a progress bar, rating stars, text, a gradient, etc. (i.e., it's not just an image).  Keep the rest of the behavior.  Scroll up and the image and all the stuff on top of it will hide so only the toolbar is visible.

Comment: Still don't totally understand what you're asking ... In my head, I'm imagining that as the page scrolls, the image itself scrolls up but the rating stars, text, etc collapse into a toolbar. It'd be super helpful if there were some images/wireframes of both states ...

Comment: no, the image and rating/text etc. are one "image"/layout.  All of it scrolls/collapses and then only the toolbar remains.  Consider it a dynamic image.  And there might be some other text under the image as well.  It'd be perfect if I could use a RelativeLayout or LinearLayout and set it up for parallax but I haven't had any luck doing that so far :-(

Comment: Well I'd love to try to help you out, but unfortunately, I just can't imagine what you're describing. Sorry, Kenyee :-(

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [CollapsingToolbarLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@color/nav_view_header"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_vp_placeholder_largo"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

            <!-- Your progress bar, rating stars, text, a gradient, etc. -->


        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!-- Your scrolling content -->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```